# Construction as "great thanks"

Tags: vocabulary

Someone really did something so great to me that thanks is simply not enough. I doubt there is such a construction "great thanks", but I really need something which has the same meaning. Also, I have no idea what to do, thank you, thank you very much and thanks are all expressions for well, thanking someone. Thanks for help!

Comment: __Eternal gratitude__ may serve.

Comment: I would simply use "Many thanks".

Comment: "Deepest gratitude", "profound thanks" and many many more.

Answer (score -1):

For thanking in a formal setting, you might use phrases like "`I can't adequately express my gratefulness/gratitude`".

A little less formal would be '`thanks a lot`'.

I would use '`thanks big time`' or '`bless you`'(only if the subject if younger or your age) in a more informal setting.

You can even use phrases like "I know not how to repay my debt of gratitude to you", but I strongly suggest against using these anachronistic phrases as they might be taken sarcastically. You may however, use them in a flippant way with close friends.

Comment: 'The debt of your gratitude' is confusing, 'your gratitude' would be gratitude felt by the other person, not the speaker, and I can't see that debt works with that. Were you reaching for 'I don't know how to repay my debt of gratitude to you'?

Comment: @Spagirl, thanks for pointing that out, correction made!

Answer (score -2):

"Thanks so much" --> Natural, expressive, precise :-D

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.